# Need a progress indicator for a Perl system() command using T:R:G mod

Tags: perl, libreadline, progress-indicator

I want a progress indicator that takes the output of a Perl

```
   system('make')
```

and for each line output to STDOUT from the make command, I want to output a dot as a progress indicator.  Unfortunately, I'm using the Term::ReadLine::Gnu Perl mod.

How do I redirect STDOUT to capture and count the lines as the make command is running?

Comment: You may also find [Term::ProgressBar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Term::ProgressBar) of use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $command = "make";

open (my $cmd, "$command |");
while(<$cmd>){
  print ".";
}
print "\n";
```

Comment: I recommend using a three-arg `open` for this: `open my $cmd, '-|', $command or die $!;`  This is safer and more efficient.

Comment: good advice, I use the three-arg version exclusively for files, why not pipes as well?  Also, this might be a case where using print over die may have its advantages.

Comment: You'll want to autoflush STDOUT otherwise it'll wait for a whole line of dots before printing.  `use IO::Handle;  STDOUT->autoflush(1)`

Comment: yeah, add $outStatus=$?; inside the while loop, then after the loop add a line like  print "$command was SUCCESSFUL\n" if ($outStatus ~~ 0);

Answer (score 4):

```
make >& >(while read f; do echo -n .; done; echo)
```

Obviously this is a shell solution, but a dot as a progress indicator is a dot.

You could of course stick a tee in there to save a copy of the make to file in case of problems.

Since you didn't seem to like (neither upvoted or accepted) the shell solution for some unexplained reason, here is a pure perl one:

```
if (open(X,"make|")) { local($|)=1; while(<X>) { print "."; } close(X); print "\n";}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of making the shell do the heavy lifting... interesting.

Comment: @bitbucket: Added a pure perl option to the previous shell answer.

Comment: I had to get some sleep...  I'm testing the solutions today.