# Need to output the action of a system() command and have a progress indicator

Tags: perl, pipe, progress-indicator

I have a nice progress indicator from [Need a progress indicator for a Perl system() command using T:R:G mod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052345)

```
open(my $cmd, '-|', "$command $flags_args 2>/dev/null")
  or print "\nAttention: Command $command $flags_args failed $!"
  and return 1;

while (<$cmd>)
{
  $percentage = ($cntr/$lines) * 100;
  $percentage = 100 if $percentage > 100;

  printf("Progress: %3d%%\r", $percentage);
  $cntr++;

}
close($cmd);
```

Now my I want logging of the STDOUT and STDERR of the commands output.  I'm not too familiar with pipe output so I tried adding:

```
print $LOG $cmd
```

and

```
print $LOG Dumper(\$cmd)
```

before the end of the while loop.  It did not work. The first output

```
GLOB(0x11df7a0)GLOB(0x11df7a0)GLOB(0x11df7a0)
```

the second

```
$VAR1 = \\*{'::$cmd'};
$VAR1 = \\*{'::$cmd'};
$VAR1 = \\*{'::$cmd'};
```

Does anyone know how I can get the output from the piped $cmd?
Example for a $command = make command

```
 Making all in src
 make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp' 
 Making all in include
 make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/2'

 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making it

```
 print $LOG $_;
```

or maybe just

```
 print $LOG;
```

(since `$_` is the default if nothing is specified)

To explain: `$cmd` is the file you're reading from; `$_` is the line read from it. You can make it clearer by writing:

```
 while ($line = <$cmd>) {
    print $LOG $line;
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Use `while ( my $line = ... )`

Comment: @friedo: Of course you're right, that's better - I just didn't want to confuse the issue with too many changes in one go :)

Answer (score 2):

`$cmd` is the I/O handle to your command's output, an internal data type that doesn't make much sense to print. You want to use `<$cmd>` or `readline($cmd)` to get the output of it, which you already do in your `while` loop:

```
while (<$cmd>)      # same as:    while (defined($_ = readline($cmd)))
{
  # last line from command is now stored in $_
  print $LOG $_;

  $percentage = ($cntr/$lines) * 100;
  $percentage = 100 if $percentage > 100;

  printf("Progress: %3d%%\r", $percentage);
  $cntr++;


}
```

Comment: Interesting about the "last line from command is not stored in $_
"

Comment: Gads! That should be "last line from command is **now** stored in $_"